# PHP str_replace() not working as expected

Tags: php, str-replace

I got this code here:

```
<?php 
include_once("php_includes/loginLinks.php");
str_replace("member_profile","php_includes/member_profile",$loginLinks);
str_replace("member_account","php_includes/member_account",$loginLinks);
str_replace("logout","php_includes/logout",$loginLinks);
str_replace("register_form","php_includes/register_form",$loginLinks);
str_replace("login","php_includes/login",$loginLinks);
echo $loginLinks;
?>
```

it's supposed to change the root folder of links, I'm pretty sure there is some logic mistake in there.

***The question:***
How to change the links directories of newly echo'ed links directories to another directory, or is it another way to change it(I'm pretty new in PHP so not really good at it)?

Comment: a) it doesn't act on reference. you have to assign the results back to `$loginLinks`, b) it would be helpful if you showed what `$loginLinks` has in it, results you are getting, and expected results

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must update the variable with the results of the `str_replace` operation like this:

```
<?php 
include_once("php_includes/loginLinks.php");
$loginLinks = str_replace("member_profile","php_includes/member_profile",$loginLinks);
$loginLinks = str_replace("member_account","php_includes/member_account",$loginLinks);
$loginLinks = str_replace("logout","php_includes/logout",$loginLinks);
$loginLinks = str_replace("register_form","php_includes/register_form",$loginLinks);
$loginLinks = str_replace("login","php_includes/login",$loginLinks);
echo $loginLinks;
?>
```

`str_replace` doesn't modify the original variable, but returns a new value. Here I update $loginLinks with the updated value.

Comment: Thank you Brandon, that helped me out,can't accept this post before 10mins have passed.

Answer (score 2):

Your mistake is you didn't assign the replacement into the `$loginLinks`. But instead of `str_replace()` use of `preg_replace()` will be much better for your need I believe.

```
$loginLinks = preg_replace(
    "/(member_profile|member_account|logout|login|register_form)/",
    "php_includes/$1",
    $loginLinks
);
```